# MySQL DATE Behavior & Result Issues

Tags: mysql, date, concatenation

MySQL Version: 8.0.18
Charset: utf8mb4
Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

I'm putting together a ruleset that converts "present" date entries to a DATE entry (since we are storing dates as actual DATE data types, not text).

In doing this, I've found something VERY odd. I wanted a ruleset where 00-00-2020 (for example) would represent "present".

When I execute this:

```
SELECT date(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-00-00'));
```

The result is '0/0/2020' as DATE result value.

However, when I execute this in my STORED PROCEDURE:

```
SET out_result_formatted_date = CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-00-00');
```

The result is always '1/1/0001'. Note out_result_formatted_date is of DATE type. Also note if I put DATE in front of the CONCAT (of the Stored Procedure) the result is the same.

Why on earth am I receiving two different results from what should be the exact same code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not surprised you are having issues, as `2020-00-00` is a bogus date which does not exist.  That being said, a better way to do this would be to use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-01-01')
SET out_result_formatted_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-01-01')
```

This builds a valid date literal on the first day and month of the current year.

Comment: So the problem here is I need a fake date entry; because I don't want to use NULL to represent "present" because sometimes dates will just be missing. So I was hoping to use a made-up (e.g. '2020-00-00') date. Technically I could use the returned 1/1/0001 but I wanted to store the year the PRESENT value was fetched, which is why I wrote the code the way I did. Unfortunately, your response doesn't address why I'm getting two completely different results with the same code.

Comment: Ultimately what I need is exactly what the SELECT date(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-00-00')) provides since it lets me know the year of the present entry. As mentioned, the issue is the stored procedure is returning a completely different result from the simple query.

Comment: You should not have the need for a bogus date.  Either use `NULL` or create a new status column.  Regarding your error, perhaps queries and procs don't behave the same way with errors.  In any case, do not attempt to use `2020-00-00` as a date.

Comment: Yah the issue here is 2020-00-00 is technically an error, but MySQL returns that without an error as a query, misleading as to its validity; but you are correct, trying to insert that into the table directly fails. I was just hoping to store the year of "present" without creating a new column. We have decided to map "present" dates to 01/01/0001. Saves data and is efficient.